# PHP OOP: Create a new class?

Tags: php, oop

I have 3 tables:

```
users:
id
first_name
last_name

courses:
id
name

student_courses:
id
student_id
course_id
paid
```

Users keeps track of the users, courses keep track of the courses, and student_courses is the table that shows what students have signed up for which courses. I currently have a "users" class and a "courses" class. My question is: Should I create a StudentCourses class to handle the interactions for the student_courses table?

ie: I need to create a function that gets all courses a user has signed up for, mark them as paid, etc.

Is it best to do:

```
$student = new User($userId); 
$student->getCourses();
$student->markCourseAsPaid($courseId);
```

OR

```
$student = new User($userId);
$studentCourses = new StudentCourses($studentId);
$studentCourses->markCourseAsPaid($courseId);
```

etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you think about your `student_courses` and `courses` tables in terms of objects, you will notice that the `student_courses` is the really interesting table as it contains the individual objects for the student. They are what you want to have your Student object connect to. What you have in `courses` now is just the [non-changing part of a course](http://www.cs.unca.edu/~manns/Coad.pdf), e.g. it's name and description. Hence, your `StudentCourse` instances can simply aggregate that. You only need to load that instance once and then share it across `StudentCourse` instances:

[image: Student hasMany Courses hasOne CourseDescription]

For [Cohesion](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29), your `markAsPaid` method should be on the [object with the most information required to fulfill it](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/GRASP_%28object-oriented_design%29#Information_Expert). In other words, it should be on `Course`. However, you can add a `payForCourse` [proxy method](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/hide-delegate) on the Student that then calls `markAsPaid` on the appropriate `Course`. You might want to introduce a `Courses` class that acts as a [Repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html).

Comment: I think I get what you're saying. How would you recommend signing a student up for a course with the following: $student = new Student($studentId); $course = new Course($courseId);

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to extend the application in the future, I'd create separate class for StudentCourse. Now it has only one additional attribute except join attributes (paid), but when you will need to add another attributes you'll going to create this class anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'd not create the separate class. My approach would be to use something like the following:

```
$student = new User($userId);
$course = new Course($courseId);
$student->markCourseAsPaid($course);
```

As the `student_courses` table is simply just a relationship, there shouldn't be an extra class. An extra class would imply that it's an entity, which it's not, it's a relationship.

My code differs from yours as I'm first fetching the appropriate `Course` instance, then passing that instance to the user. In my opinion it's weird to pass just the ID of the course, since then the `User` object just receives a number as parameter, which has no meaning at all. We might not have to ID (primary key) of the course, but a secondary key. Then this method becomes useless since it expects the PK, not some SK. Because I choose to fetch the `Course` object first we don't have this problem, as the Course object does know how to retrieve the correct course by a secondary key.

**Edit**: As this is an objectified relationship, there may be some point in using the extra class. But then I'd go with another approach:

```
$studentCourse = new StudentCourse($studentId, $courseId);
$studentCourse->markPaid();
```

As both the student ID and course ID make up for the secondary key of the table, they should both be specified in the constructor.

Comment: Wouldn't dropping line 2, and `$student->markCourseAsPaid($courseId);` be a better choice... no need to load the course information (complete with database trip) for this command, well unless `new Course($courseId);` uses lazy loading (which is effectively the same as not creating it)

Comment: @Rudu yes I was working on that explanation ;) I indeed expect the ORM classes to be smart enough not to load any values until they're actually requested.

Answer (score 0):

Well in this case it looks like either may work.

usually you would make each model/table a class (i.e. a Student, a Course, a User etc.) in an MVC (model-view-controller) paradigm. Then in each class you might have a variable to relate them. I don't see the need for the StudentCourses class even though the table structure shows a relationship there should be no need for another class. The first example looks more object oriented to me. Again you could do it either way but I always opt for more object-oriented code myself.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a third class for `course_student` that would rely on a `table` on your database AND a `view` for the following reason, separation of concerns.

You view is used for all the select and the table for insert, update and delete.

Your view would be composed of all the relevant fields of both tables (using 2 `inner join`) (students and courses) based on the relations in your `course_student` table

A row will look like :

```
student_id, student_first_name, student_last_name, courses_id, courses_name, is_paid
```

If you want to get all the students taking a course you can have a method named `getStudentsByCourse(courseId)`.

If you want to get all the courses of a specific student you can have a method named `getStudentCourses(studentId)`.

If you need to register a set of students for a course (or many) you can have a method named `setStudentsCourses(studentId, courseId)` (where both parameters can be either integers or array.